# MySQL query numbers +10 with limitation

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores date like this

```
E1 = day
E2 = month
E3 = year
```

I know it's weird already

Now I need to mass update every (E1) and add to it +10 days but if that (E1) is let's say 28 then it will be 38 how can I update it correctly?

```
UPDATE eventfile SET E1=E1 + 10
```

Comment: Don't you want to update e2 and e3?

Comment: What do you mean by 'update it correctly'?

Comment: i mean updating the E1 with E2 and E3 at the same time without leaving out any days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must update all columns `E1`, `E2` and `E3` so that the new date is reflected correctly.
You can construct a date from the integer values of `E1`, `E2` and `E3` with [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), add 10 days to that date and then update the columns:

```
UPDATE eventfile e
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *, STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(e1, '-', e2, '-', e3), '%e-%c-%Y') + INTERVAL 10 day date
  FROM eventfile
) t ON (t.e1, t.e2, t.e3) = (e.e1, e.e2, e.e3)
SET e.e1 = DAY(t.date),
    e.e2 = MONTH(t.date),
    e.e3 = YEAR(t.date)
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3f46cd72318d2c1ae16657158d415af5).

Comment: Thank you,
I got this error "incorrect datetime value '2021-02-31'"

Comment: @iN4sser the 2nd row contains an invalid date. There is no 31st of February. Also remove the `,` from the column E3. Conclusion: fix your data.

Comment: Thank you very much, yeah that was the problem from other solutions
now it's working